# Why does xcolor not like \fbox (or vice versa)?

Tags: errors, color, boxes

This document would not compile and a rather cryptic `! Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted)` pops up. Here's the MnWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\renewcommand{\fboxrule}{0.9pt}

\begin{document}
\fbox{\colorbox{yellow}{\rule[-1.25ex]{0pt}{4ex}\hspace{1em}\textbf{Random Text}\hspace{1em}}}
\end{document}
```

The funny thing that puzzles me is that it turns immediately into a *working* example when I use `color` instead of `xcolor`. What does `xcolor` break? Why is the error related to units? What has the color got to do with it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`\fboxrule` must be treated as a length macro!

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\setlength{\fboxrule}{0.9pt}
% the following is also fine.
% \relax is optional here.
% \fboxrule=0.9pt\relax

\begin{document}
\fbox{\colorbox{yellow}{\rule[-1.25ex]{0pt}{4ex}\hspace{1em}\textbf{Random Text}\hspace{1em}}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Okay, I get that, but still: why? Why did it work and why did `xcolor` break it and not some other random package?

Comment: @CountZero: Please break my MWE above to illustrate the problem.

Comment: Your MWE is perfectly fine, I'm just very curious why in my MWE things went wrong?

Comment: @CountZero: Because of your wrong setting `\renewcommand{\fboxrule}{0.9pt}`.

Comment: @CountZero Garbage Collector explained that your document contains a serious mistake: trying to `\renewcommand` a length. If you correct this, you gon't get any mistakes. I don't think it makes much sense to analyze where and why user mistake bubbled to a mistake related to some package, as long as it's obviously a user mistake.

Answer (score 4):

If you're using `xcolor` then there is the `\fcolorbox` command at your disposal

Try:

```
\fcolorbox{black}{yellow}{\rule[-1.25ex]{0pt}{4ex}\hspace{1em}\textbf{Random Text}\hspace{1em}}
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\setlength{\fboxrule}{0.9pt}
\setlength{\fboxsep}{3pt}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

\fcolorbox{black}{yellow}{\rule[-1.25ex]{0pt}{4ex}\hspace{1em}\textbf{Random Text}\hspace{1em}}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that `\fboxrule` and `\fboxsep` are lengths and not commands.  To change their values, you need to use `\setlength{\fboxrule}{<dim>}`

Also, to avoid the *messiness* of `\rule...\hspace...<content>\hspace...` you could define your own command as

```
\newcommand{\myfbox}[1]{{\setlength{\fboxsep}{1em}%
                         \fcolorbox{black}{yellow}{#1}%
                       }}
```

I've used `{{...}}` to ensure that `\setlength` only changes the value of `\fboxsep` for the purposes of the new command.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\setlength{\fboxrule}{0.9pt}
\setlength{\fboxsep}{3pt}
\pagestyle{empty}

\newcommand{\myfbox}[1]{{\setlength{\fboxsep}{\dimexpr1em+3pt\relax}%
                         \fcolorbox{black}{yellow}{#1}%
                       }}

\begin{document}

\myfbox{\textbf{Random Text}} \fbox{\textbf{Random Text}}

\fcolorbox{black}{yellow}{\rule[-1.25ex]{0pt}{4ex}\hspace{1em}\textbf{Random Text}\hspace{1em}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

You could go so far as to do:

```
\newcommand{\myfboxB}[1]{\fcolorbox{black}{yellow}
                            {\raisebox{0pt}%%                                   don't raisebox
                                      [\dimexpr-1.25ex+4ex\relax]%%             change the height of box
                                      [\dimexpr1.25ex\relax]%%                  change the depth of box
                                      {\makebox[\dimexpr\width+2em\relax]{#1}%% change width of box
                                      }}}
```

which will reproduce a box looking just like yours.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\setlength{\fboxrule}{0.9pt}
\setlength{\fboxsep}{3pt}
\pagestyle{empty}

\newcommand{\myfbox}[1]{{\setlength{\fboxsep}{\dimexpr1em+3pt\relax}%
                         \fcolorbox{black}{yellow}{#1}%
                       }}

\newcommand{\myfboxB}[1]{\fcolorbox{black}{yellow}
                            {\raisebox{0pt}%%                                   don't raisebox
                                      [\dimexpr-1.25ex+4ex\relax]%%             change the height of box
                                      [\dimexpr1.25ex\relax]%%                  change the depth of box
                                      {\makebox[\dimexpr\width+2em\relax]{#1}%% change width of box
                                      }}}

\begin{document}

\myfbox{\textbf{Random Text}} \fbox{\textbf{Random Text}}

\fcolorbox{black}{yellow}{\rule[-1.25ex]{0pt}{4ex}\hspace{1em}\textbf{Random Text}\hspace{1em}}
\myfboxB{\textbf{Random Text}}     

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, great answer! Unfortunately I can accept only 1 answer and the document I am working with is rather long with lots of `\fbox`es all over the place. I'm too lazy to clean that up now. Anyway, definitely: +1!

Comment: No problem. I just thought I could show you a bit more what you could do and how you can make your file a bit easier to read.